# Cannot config or rewrite routing in ASP.NET MVC Web Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes, url-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC Web Api. I am rewriting routing for my api to make the urls neat. But it is not working.

I have action method in ItemsController like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri]string keyword = "", [FromUri]int category = 0, [FromUri]int region = 0, [FromUri]int area = 0, [FromUri]int page = 0,[FromUri]int count = 0)
{
.
.
.
}
```

In WebApiConfig I config routing for that action like this:

```
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "",
            routeTemplate: "api/v1/places/{category}/{region}/{area}/{page}/{count}",
            defaults: new { controller = "ItemsController" , keyword = "" , category = 0 , region = 0 ,area = 0 , page = 0 , count = 0 }
        );
```

As you can see, I did not set keyword in route. But when I access from below url, it is giving me error.

This is how I make get request:

```
http://localhost:50489/api/v1/places/0/0/0/1/2
```

This is the error:

```
{
    "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:50489/api/v1/places/0/0/0/1/2'.",
    "MessageDetail": "No type was found that matches the controller named 'ItemsController'."
}
```

How can I rewrite it? I want to make exclude keyword in that url. I will have another route for that action as well.

This is not working as well:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "",
                routeTemplate: "api/v1/places/{keyword}/{category}/{region}/{area}/{page}/{count}",
                defaults: new { controller = "ItemsController" , keyword = "" , category = 0 , region = 0 ,area = 0 , page = 0 , count = 0 }
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates your controller doesn't exist.

This is because Web API is looking for a controller named `ItemsControllerController`. The suffix `Controller` is added automatically by the framework. So, if your controller is actually named `ItemsController`, your route should be:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "",
        routeTemplate: "api/v1/places/{category}/{region}/{area}/{page}/{count}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Items" , keyword = "" , category = 0 , region = 0 ,area = 0 , page = 0 , count = 0 }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Dummy query below try to use this way..just make changes accordingly

Api code:

```
[Route("api/{Home}/{Username}/{Password}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(string Username, string Password)
        {
//code here
}
```

**WebApiConfig**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
            config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
            config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();


            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
             name: "DefaultApi",
             routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
             defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
         );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ContactApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{Username}/{Password}"
            );


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET Web API 2, then you can have go for the code snippet provided by @stylishCoder [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2).

This  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095311/http-post-multiple-objects-through-postasjsonasync/34102633#34102633) will help you pass multiple objects to an endpoint.